# Firefox Private Tabs from Command Line

Tags: batch-file, firefox, tabs, command-line-arguments

I am trying to make a batch file that would launch Firefox.

I need to open one private Firefox window with two tabs in it. I tried various combinations of `-new-tab` and `-private-window`, but I can't seem to achieve the desired result.

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -private-window https://www.google.com/ -new-tab https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options
```

I do not want to use the so called *permanent private browsing mode* (`-private`), because it lacks visual confirmation that it is in private mode.

The reason I want this to be a batch file and not a link is because of the character limit with Windows links (I am on Windows).

Comment: AFAIK if you starting GUI program, you do not need to use `start` command. Just start firefox directly with parameters append.

Comment: Noted from the page in your URL, **-private-window URL** _Does not work on Firefox 48 on Windows 7_. If you have the latest version of Firefox on Windows 7, I'm guessing that this could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the [private TAB](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/private-tab/?src=api) extension :

Then :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -url private:https://www.google.com/ -new-tab private:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options
```

This will open 2 **private TABs** in the actually working Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There's a command line option for making the new tab private:

```
firefox --private https://stackoverflow.com
```